# React state and JSON and arrays => faulty result

Tags: json, reactjs, iteration, local-storage, states

Edit: So, I found the solution to my initial question, which made me realize I have another issue.

It seemed to be easier than I thought

```
setNumbers(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var already_exists = false;
    var ls_data = this.state.storedNumbers;

    var rname = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var rnumb = document.getElementById('nummer').value;
    var ls_key = this.state.ls_key;

    for (key in ls_data) {
        if(ls_data.hasOwnProperty(key) === true) {
            if(ls_data[key].name === rname) {
                if(ls_data[key].Number === rnumb) {
                    already_exists = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(!already_exists) {
        ls_key++;
        ls_data[ls_key] = {
            name: rname,
            Number: rnumb
        };

        localStorage.setItem("ls_numbers", JSON.stringify(this.state.storedNumbers));
        localStorage.setItem("ls_key", ls_key); 

        this.setState({
            ls_key: localStorage.getItem("ls_key"),
        });

    }
}
```

But now my issue is, that I can't iterate over it, because it is a nested object and not an array. So .map will not work (this.state.storedNumbers.map is not a function).

Changing storedNumber to an array sadly doesn't solve the issue, as

```
        ls_data[ls_key] = {
            name: rname,
            Number: rnumb
        };
```

isn't working in an array. So now my question is. Can I use my ls_key variable to create a name object in my array? Using the code above results in:

```
[
    null,
    {
        "name" : "Person 1",
        "Number" : "XXXXXXXX"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Person 2",
        "Number" : "XXXXXXXX"
    }
]
```

while the array should look like:

```
[
    "1": {
        "name" : "Person 1",
        "Number" : "XXXXXXXX"
    },
    "2": {
        "name" : "Person 2",
        "Number" : "XXXXXXXX"
    }
]
```

Or is there a way to iterate over the nested JSON result, as .map does for an array?

Comment: Is that the only place you are mutating the storedNumbers state? One thing to keep in mind is that setState is asynchronous but that is definitely not the reason of malforming your object.

Comment: It is indeed the only place. Once the data is set correctly, I’ll run a map to display the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright then, just figured it out myself:

The reason my data got malformed (initial question), still in the blue about that. I've changed a lot of code and reverted to the original code again, et voila, miraculously it all worked. Can't tell you what the difference was. After that I could easily simplify the code as shown in the edited question.

To iterate over the data, the code below was my solution. Should you have a more cleaner solution, let me know!

```
{this.state.storedNumbers.length < 1
    ?   <li className='list-group-item'><strong>Geen recente nummers...</strong><span className='pull-right'><span className='glyphicon glyphicon-warning glyph-xl'></span></span></li>
    :   Object.keys(this.state.storedNumbers).map((number) => { 
            return (
                <div className='item' key={number}>
                    <a className='list-group-item list-link'>
                        <strong>{this.state.storedNumbers[number].name}</strong> - ({this.state.storedNumbers[number].Number})
                    </a>
                    <span className='button-delete glyph-xl'>
                        <i className='glyphicon glyphicon-trash glyph-xl' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            )})
}
```